# event versus amend in synrc/bpe

Tags: erlang, workflow, business-process-management, n2o

I'm new to workflow engines. And I want to describe and run my processes using [synrc/bpe](https://github.com/synrc/bpe).
There are functions `bpe:amend/2` and `bpe:event/2`. What these used for
and what's the difference between them?